# SQL selecting rows with same field value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The initial table is something like this

```
id  name        count
1   chocolate   5 
1   cheeze      3 
2   pepperoni   2
2   potatoes    1
2   cheese      7
3   dirty sock  2
```

What i want is to select the rows that have different ids but have the same name. In other words the ingredients that would be used in more recipes

Comment: So just do a select by name? I must be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: in your example all names are different, even `cheese` != `cheeze`. Can you give more detailed example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get your unique id, name pairs as a subquery, then aggregate the results by name.

```
select name, COUNT(*) as count
from (
    select distinct id, name
    from mytable) as sq
group by name
```

Comment: Alternatively,
    SELECT t1.id FROM myTable t1, myTable t2
        WHERE t1.name LIKE t2.name AND t1.id != t2.id;

Comment: would have been sweet but the recipe table doesnt have the ingredients listed

Comment: This is weird, but this accepted answer does not agree with the question, not even close: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/506d8/8) - it shows ingredients that were used once overall. In question, you asked for duplicates.

Comment: He never asked for "duplicates", he asked to be able to see which ingredients were used in more recipes.  This enables him to see how many recipes an ingredient is used in, thus, solving the problem.

Comment: Quoting question: `What i want is to select the rows that have different ids but have the same name`

Comment: `In other words the ingredients that would be used in more recipes` - I took the latter statement as a better explanation of what the OP was looking for.

Comment: `potatoes` is used in just one recipe, yet your query displays it. How this could be possibly what was asked?

Comment: Everything was used in just one recipe :)

Comment: Whatever, I am not going to fight it. But having wrong answer to be accepted is just bad for future site visitors.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you wanted to select duplicates by name. In your example that should have been `cheese` if you used the same spelling (but you didn't - is it mistake?).

Assuming I got it right, this should work ([SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/506d8/1)):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE [name] IN (
    SELECT [name]
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY [name]
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: yes, you got it right

Answer (score 0):

Tried to post in comment above, formatting didn't quite work out; this works as well:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM myTable t1, myTable t2
    WHERE t1.name LIKE t2.name AND t1.id != t2.id;
```

Comment: I thought he was looking for the ingredient (name) that occurred most often amongst recipes (id).  How does this solve his problem?

Answer (score 0):

select name, count(id) as used_in_recipes
from ingredients 
group by name;

Do we really need to check for a different id?
why would i need to repeat the same ingredient in a recipe?

Just let's group them by name.